# Rake task failing with `source: not found` on Heroku

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, virtualenv

I have a Rails project with a rake task called `update_data`, which is as follows:

```
every 1.day, :at => '2:30 am' do
  root = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
  system("""(source #{root}/data_scripts/venv/bin/activate;
             python #{root}/data_scripts/scripts/main.py;
             deactivate)""")
end
```

This should first activate the virtualenv, run the script, and then deactivate the virtualenv.
 When I run `rake update_data`, this works perfectly. However, when I run `heroku run rake update_data`, it fails with `sh: 1: source: not found`. What should I do so that `source` is available on Heroku?

Comment: I think `#{root}/data_scripts/venv/bin/python data_scripts/scripts/main.py` should work too. Though, in this case it looks like the problem is not in the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `sh: 1: source: not found` means that:

1. you run `sh` instead of `bash`,
2. `source` is not a built-in command and the shell isn't able to find `source` in `PATH`.

To confirm this run `heroku run sh`, type `source` and compare the output with trying to execute `foobar`.

I recommend you try passing the command to bash (via `bash -c "your command goes here"). You may also need a Python buildpack. You can add it with:

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
```

Comment: `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python` fails with `Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks
/heroku/python.tgz` when I try to push to heroku master.

Comment: You need to add `requirements.txt` to the root directory. Please see [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you don't need to activate your virtualenv.

Just use the virtualenv's python executable:

```
every 1.day, :at => '2:30 am' do
  root = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
  system("#{root}/data_scripts/venv/bin/python #{root}/data_scripts/scripts/main.py")
end
```

Comment: With this, I get `/app/data_scripts/venv/bin/python: 9: /app/data_scripts/venv/bin/python: Syntax error: EOF in back
quote substitution`. It seems like the heroku environment is not configured to run Python?